# XML - Move To Last Child

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I'm trying to figure out how to select the last child of the currently selected xml node. I'm having a bit of trouble.

the xml document starts out like this

```
<project>
   <book>
    ...
   </book>
   <characters>
     <character>
      .....
     </character>
   </characters>
 </project>
```

I need to be able to append a new character element inside characters along with child nodes inside with data.

I've used an if else statement for if characters node exists and if not. I'm working on the if it does exist now. Basically the document will already contain one character.

Here's the code I'm working with right now.

```
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("/project/characters")
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "character", "", "")
        nav.SelectSingleNode("//project/characters/*[last()]")
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "name", "", characterName)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "race", "", characterRace)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "age", "", characterAge)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "name", "", characterName)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "race", "", characterRace)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "age", "", characterAge)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "gender", "", characterGender)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "origin", "", characterOrigin)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "eye", "", characterEyeColor)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "hair", "", characterHairColor)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "weight", "", characterWeight)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "height", "", characterHeight)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "occupation", "", characterOccupation)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "birthmarks", "", characterBirthmarks)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "piercings", "", characterPiercings)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "tattoos", "", characterTattoos)
        nav.AppendChildElement("", "scars", "", characterScars)

        Do While counter < traitCount

            nav.AppendChildElement("", "trait", "", characterTraits.AsReadOnly(counter))

            counter = counter + 1
        Loop

        counter = 0

        Do While counter < habitCount

            nav.AppendChildElement("", "habit", "", characterHabits.AsReadOnly(counter))

            counter = counter + 1
        Loop

        nav.AppendChildElement("", "bio", "", characterBio)


        document.Save(ProjectDataMod.projectPathMod + ProjectDataMod.projectNameMod + ".xml")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Jb.

Comment: Are you asking how to select the last child element, whatever that happens to be, or are you asking, specifically, how to select the new child element that you just appended?

Comment: I need to get inside the element that I just appended, or inside the last child of the selected node, which would be the node that I just appended, lol. The code so far adds a child node <character> at the end of <characters> but it doesn't append the elements inside that node... I need to get the data elements <name> <race> and so on inside the newly appended child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

You could use XPath for this. If I understand right you want the last child of the "characters" node:

```
nav.SelectSingleNode( "//project/characters/*[last()]" )
```

If you have several characters nodes you could do:

```
nav.SelectSingleNode( "//project/characters[last()]/*[last()]" )
```

To get the last child of the last characters node.

Comment: Shouldn't that call to the xpath count() function be removed?

Comment: Edited answer, think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This didn't quite work. I did.  nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("/project/characters")
            nav.AppendChildElement("", "character", "", "")
            nav.SelectSingleNode("//project/characters/*[last()]")
            nav.AppendChildElement("", "name", "", characterName)                                                          but this created.     <characters><character></character><character></character> a bunch of character data </characters>

Comment: I have one characters node and inside a child node character, and inside that data pertaining to the character. Right now I can add one character and data, but I can't figure out how to append a character node and data at the end of characters..

Comment: sorry, I updated my code in the question to match what I thought you meant. It appends a child node character to characters but it doesn't write the data in the correct place. It jumps over the newly appended node and writes it inside characters.

Comment: I will try on my machine when i'm home this weekend and get back to you with my result :)

Comment: I just figured it out. You were just about right, but it should have been.  nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("//project/characters/*[last()]")

Comment: Thanks for your help. Helped me get to where I needed to be :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) to [query](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) your xml. It has a built in function to find the last child of a node.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301220

Comment: Any idea how this would work. I'm not that knowledgeable on navigating xml at all.. Just learning now..

Comment: the last link shows an example project from microsoft that teaches how it works.

Comment: I tried Sweet Lou's  method as I thought it should be. See the updated code in the question. Didn't quite do what I wanted. It appended the character node inside characters but didn't add the character information inside... I'll try reading the article you linked...ahh if you could check the updated code in the question maybe you could tell me why it doesn't work? Thanks for all help and information :)